# Is there an alternative method to using 15 If statements?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have 15 items in my `ComboBox` and when the user selects an item I want to present something different in my `TextBox`.

At the moment I have:

```
If cb_dropdown.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    RTB_Sql.Text = "update access
set accessdesc = 'Less than 5' where accessID < '5'"
Else
    If cb_dropdown.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        RTB_Sql.Text = "update access
set accessdesc = 'More than 5' where accessID > '5' and < '10' "
    Else
        If cb_dropdown.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            RTB_Sql.Text = ""
```

etc....

Is there a nicer and more methodical way to approach this as it looks quite scruffy?

Comment: There's the `CASE` but that's basically a glorified IF.

Comment: Case statements... But after reviewing your code you can wrap all that up easily if the comparison you are doing is the only thing...

Comment: On another note, there's cleaner ways to write db statements as the way you are doing it is insufficient...

Comment: You can prepare dictionary and query texts (dictionary values) by dropdown index - no `if`s or `case`s needed.

Comment: you could also store a simple object in your cbo to show one thing and return the related data you are conjuring up.  All that becomes:  `RTB_Sql.Text = cb_dropdown.SelectedValue.ToString`

Comment: If you include the entire list of **If** statements, maybe we could suggest definite ways of cleaning it up. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is called [select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx).

```
Select Case cb_dropdown.SelectedIndex
    Case 0 To 4
        RTB_Sql.Text = "update access
set accessdesc = 'Less than 5' where accessID < '5'"
    Case 5
        RTB_Sql.Text = [...]
    Case Else
        RTB_Sql.Text = [...]
End Case
```

Although in your case I think what you are looking for is < (less than) and > (greater than).

```
If cb_dropdown.SelectedIndex < 5 Then
    RTB_Sql.Text = "update access set accessdesc = 'Less than 5' where accessID < '5'"
ElseIf cb_dropdown.SelectedIndex < 10 Then
    RTB_Sql.Text = "update access set accessdesc = 'More than 5' where accessID > '5' and < '10' "
End If
```

Not really sure what you are trying to do though. Maybe if you explain in more detail someone can provide a better answer. So let me take a wild guess:

```
Dim n As Integer = cb_dropdown.SelectedIndex * 5
RTB_Sql.Text = "update access set accessdesc = 'More than " + n + "' where accessID > '" + n + "' and < '" + (n+6) + "' "
```

This will give you the following result based on SelectedIndex:

- 0 = from 1 to including 5
- 1 = from 6 to including 10
- etc...

If you want to shift it down one (include 0 and not 5 in first batch) then just change > to >= and 6 to 5.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. 

Basically I want each item to run a different SQL script, not necessarily set & updates. the sql is benign in this scenario.  I will try case, as If statements are very ugly

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this if you want to check range of values:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim i As Integer = 6

        Select Case True
            Case 0 <= i AndAlso i < 5
                Console.WriteLine("i is between 0 and 4")

            Case 6 <= i
                Console.WriteLine("i is 6 or greater")
        End Select



        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Be aware that it stops in the first true condition.